# Django Calculate data on related models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I'm new to Django. Just want to know what's the best way to calculate some data of two related models. I've got an `Order` and `OrderLine` model so every time I add a new `OrderLine` item I want to iterate through all `OrderLine` items for that order and recalculate its total, and update the `Order` model with that total. Here's my models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    """
    Order model
    """

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    session_id = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    subtotal = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2,
        max_digits=20,
        default=0.00)
    total = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=0.00)

    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class OrderLine(models.Model):
    """
    OrderLine contains data related to the items added to an order
    """
    order_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Order,
        related_name='items',
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    total = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)

    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_id
```

So I've thought of 2 options:

1. Create a `post_save` signal in `OrderLine` which will query all items in `OrderLine` with `order_id` of the order that was just saved, iterate through each one, calculate the total and then assign it to the order total and update it
2. Simply create a method in `OrderLine` call something like `recalculate_total`. This method will receive an order id, will iterate through order lines with that id, return the calculated total.

Any advice?

Comment: Signals are generally considered to be anti-patterns, so I would either use option (2), or override the `.save()` method of `OrderLine` to compute the total and persist it in the `Order` method. The latter might come in handy if you will use the total for queries (such as `Order.objects.filter(orderline_total__gt=0)`)

Comment: @Selcuk thanks for replying back. Just curious, if I override `save()` in `OrderLine` I'd need to access the `Order` model in order to update the total value. Wouldn't this be creating a highly coupled dependency?

Comment: Yes, but your `OrderLine` model is already coupled to `Order` with a `ForeignKey` relation.